# Convert USDZ to GLTF (programmatically command line or SDK, ideally not involving Maya or Blender)

Tags: 3d, gltf, file-conversion, usdz

What is the current best practice for converting a usdz file (say, from Object Capture) to gltf?

Answer (score 0):

Any practical way of working with USDZ files will probably rely on the USD SDK (https://github.com/PixarAnimationStudios/USD). Authoring tools like Maya and Blender likely already use that, but I don't know of commandline tools or general-purpose converters that integrate it and support USD or USDZ. A combination of the USD SDK and cgltf (https://github.com/jkuhlmann/cgltf) might be a good place to start, but you'll need to understand both formats pretty well to write such a converter.

Comment: I had assumed there might be more frameworks available now that it has been several years...

Comment: USD is more a framework than a file format, in my opinion. It isn't meant to be re-implemented in the way that formats like glTF or OBJ would be. I don't know what the practical obstacles would be to writing a converter based on the USD Runtime though, or why that hasn't happened yet.